# Save key stroke events to spreadsheet +timings

Tags: javascript, keycode

As part of my college dissertation I am trying to test out how usable several different types of number entry keyboard interfaces are. To do this I need to record each key press my participants make and the timings of each key press. It is not enough just to record what they submit on a form as I need to monitor how many errors they see and correct also. I am hoping to somehow write this information to a .csv/spreadsheet to analyse after the experiments.

My supervisor suggested creating a webpage and using javascript for this but unfortunately I am a total beginner. My knowledge is limited to HTML. Could somebody please help me or suggest a place where I could find more information on this subject? I have been searching the web for the last couple of days with very little luck. Essentially I want to do something like in this example http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events#test-stand-test-stand except to write it to an external file on my computer and with the inclusion of timings for the key presses.

Many thanks,

A desperate student.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write JavaScript directly to a file. You could instead send the data to the server to save a file in the `.csv` format to a specified location. Alternatively you could output the data in a format which copies easily into excel.

I suggest setting up a `Node.js` server and using `jQuery`+`AJAX` to send the data to your server via `POST` request then saving a `.csv` file on the server.